# Объясните как работает код и почему в arithmeticMean(4, 7, 9, 5, 6) выводит результат 6.2?

Tags: swift, функции

```
func arithmeticMean(_ numbers: Double...) -> Double {
    var total: Double = 0
    for number in numbers {
        total += number
    }
    return total / Double(numbers.count)
}

arithmeticMean(4, 7, 9, 5, 6)
```

Comment: @Санаев глупые вопросы не только не запрещены, но иногда даже поощряются

Comment: Это же `Swift`, какие циклы? `let total = numbers.reduce(0, +)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Функция возвращает среднее значение массива:`4,7,9,5,6`

**Работает это следующем образом:**

`4+7+9+5+6=31` - total

`31/5=6.2` - ваш результат